# Answering question using resource from web

Tags: support, answers, link-only-answers, attribution

1. Is it wrong in Stack Overflow to answer a question copy something from web (not exactly in Stack Overflow)?
2. Should I inform about that site from where I copy the answer?

Comment: Is it a wrong question?

Comment: Nope, it's a fine question - the downvotes are likely meaning to say "no, it's not OK to copy&paste content from elsewhere on the web"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general copy-pasting content is not going to make for a good answer. By all means be inspired by content that is already out there, but try to answer the question with an answer of your own. An exception there could be a relevant quote from a specification or official documentation.

And as always, make sure to make your answer self-contained. Don't just reference an off-site resource and tell the OP to go take a look there.

If you do draw inspiration from another resource, and that resource allows you to share part of their content, [then please do indeed cite the original source](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Give credit where credit is due.